# Loading a project on a Windows 11 directory from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, path, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm trying to move a Common Lisp project over to Linux Mint from Windows 11. The program runs fine under Windows 11 SBCL. However, there is a problem loading the project in SBCL under Linux.

Running `(asdf:load-system "ww-wouldwork-planner")` produces the error asdf/find-component:missing-component, component "ww-wouldwork-planner" not found.

My init.lisp file in my Linux home directory contains `(setq *default-pathname-defaults*  #p"/media/dave/DATA/Users Data/Dave/SW Library/AI/Planning/Wouldwork Planner/")` and `(push *default-pathname-defaults* asdf:*central-registry*)`.

I've tried `(asdf:initialize-source-registry)` and verified that `asdf:*central-registry*` contains the correct directory as specified in `*default-pathname-defaults*` (on a Windows 11 partition).

Is the problem related to accessing a Windows 11 directory from Linux? Appreciate any help diagnosing the error.

Comment: I don't think it is a Windows11-vs-Linux problem. Rather that you didn't install `ww-wouldwork-planner` in your linux. By the way - probably you should just use `roswell`. https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-set-up-common-lisp-ide-in-2021-5be70d88975b
Or at last `quicklisp`.

Comment: Where is your linux running? In WSL2? Or by dual boot? And you when dual boot Linux Mint - you try to access Windows 11 folder from your Linux?

Comment: Yes, I dual-boot Windows 11 and Linux, which are installed on separate hard disks. After running init.lisp on Linux SBCL  `*default-pathname-defaults*` points to the Windows 11 source code folder (also containing the ASD definition file). I can see all the source files from Linux. (ps: not sure about "that you didn't install...". I'm expecting installation to occur with `(asdf:load-system "ww-wouldwork-planner" :force t)` in SBCL in Linux. Is it required to duplicate all the source files to a Linux directory under the root directory?

Comment: yes,I would try that first.

Comment: The solution below avoids all that redundancy & maintenance headaches. Thanks for the discussion to help me eventually see the best road forward.

Answer (score 1):

One way to resolve the problem is to first navigate to the Windows 11 source code directory from Linux, and then run `(asdf:load-system "ww-wouldwork-planner")` in SBCL. ASDF can then readily find the ASD file in that directory.

It's possible this problem may relate to the different ways Windows and Linux organize their respective file systems. Linux appears to build the whole file tree off of a single root, while Windows builds a grove of trees, one for each drive partition (C:, D:, etc). The Windows drives all appear in Linux under /media, while user files are under /home, where ASDF evidently expects to find project files. For example, moving the project files under the /home directory allows ASDF to find them. This is mostly conjecture on my part, so feel free to correct or update these provisional comments.